# What is the rationale of screen tearing?

Tags: screen, fullscreen, display, dxgi, tearing

I'm using a screen with 60Hz refresh rate. And I call present(0,0) once per 33ms.
The tearing still occur. Why?
How does a screen to show a picture? Does it scan the window last for 16.6ms or may be just in 2ms?

I'm using windows fullscreen exclusive mode. And I believe that I can control the display so if I send frames with a steady interval, tearing are not expected to occur. However, the pictures are always tearing.

Comment: It's expected that you see tearing if you present w/o syncing with the screen and the screen and/or graphic card doesn't support/isn't configured etc. for variable rate refresh. Try Present(1,0). Also you should avoid FSE if possible https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/demystifying-full-screen-optimizations/.

Comment: I'm confused about the rationale of screen showing a picture. What is the basic logic to avoid tearing?

Comment: To avoid tearing, the simplest logic is to use swapchain's Present(1,...). But this may slow down overall fps, depends on your context, and may not be needed for modern hardware setups. Just use google, for ex: https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/cqm0g0/help_understanding_screentearing/ https://www.maketecheasier.com/what-is-vsync/